# How to use htaccess for content negotiation?

Tags: .htaccess, uri, content-negotiation

In order for the content to be available through the same link, even if the file extension has changed, URI's shouldnt change. So i decided to use content negotiation and htaccess to achieve this. I searched the web but all i found out about is how to implement this specific to php. In my site i have not only php but also html, images and javascript files.
How can i use content negotiation with just htaccess?

Comment: *(reference)* https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Comment: I always create folders, and put a index.php or index.html file into it. That way if I ever swap html for php the url will still work.